# D3D12 SetPredication performance

Tags: c++, direct3d

Have a question about SetPredication on D3D12.

We are trying to use it for occlusion culling. However it seems that SetPredication makes the frame really slow.

This pseudo-code describes what we are doing:

```
BeginQuery(Occlusion);
    DrawAABB() for each model;
EndQuery(Occlusion);
ResolveQuery();
foreach (model)
{
    SetPredication(QueryResult, DrawIfNotZero);
    Draw(model);
}
```

And this is 10-20ms slower than just draw all the models without occlusion culling, i.e.:

```
foreach (model)
{
    Draw(model);
}
```

To figure out the bottleneck I did a simple test:

```
ClearBuffer(QueryResult,0);
foreach (model)
{
    SetPredication(QueryResult, DrawIfZero);
    Draw(model);
}
```

It seems that just by adding SetPredication before a draw call, the frame suddenly becomes really slow.

I'm guessing SetPredication is doing some implicit syncs on GPU, but didn't find any documents on that.

Has anyone used SetPredication for culling before?

Thanks.

Comment: please read [ask] and rewrite your question. Thank you. I think in this case, you should especially provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question, can you open it again if it looks OK to you?

Comment: looks *much* better, now someone certainly might answer it (i myself don't have any D3D knowledge, i'm afraid)